Mublazor Autocomplete Render Custom HTML
I have to display cities of a country in a Group form, for example my data source is a dictionary like
Country1
City1
City2
City3
Country2
City1
City4
City5
City6
If user search for City2, I need to show Country1 as a heading and then City1 under that heading and If user search for City1, I need to show Country1 and then City and then Country2 and City1
I have done similar thing in Bootstrap and it rendered like

Country1
City1
Country2
City1

and then I can add css to adjust spaces.
So question is, how can I render customer HTML in Blazor Autocpmplete?
This is what I want to achieve but in Mudblazor autocomplete
 _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
    var that = this,
        currentCountry = "";
    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
        var li;
        if (item.country != currentCountry) {
            ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-country pl-2 pt-2 font-weight-bold'>" + item.country + "</li>");
            currentCountry = item.country;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
    });
},
_renderItem: function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append('<div class="place-name font-weight-lighter pb-2 pl-3">' + item.city+
            '</br><span class="font-weight-normal" style="font-size:12px;"></span></div>')
        .appendTo(ul);
}

Update 1: Thank you (Fengzhi Zhou) for the answer, I had to make a minor change but I got it working. I added AfterItemsTemplate
<MudAutocomplete T="City" Label="Search City" @bind-Value="selectedCity"
             SearchFunc="@SearchCities" ToStringFunc="@(c => c == null ? null : $"{c.Country} - {c.Name}")">
<ItemTemplate Context="city">
    <MudText>
        @if (previousCountry == null || previousCountry != city.Country)
        {
            <div class="country-heading">@city.Country</div>
            previousCountry = city.Country;
        }
        <div class="city-name">@city.Name</div>
    </MudText>
</ItemTemplate>
<AfterItemsTemplate>
    @{
        previousCountry = null;
    }
</AfterItemsTemplate>


Now the City1 looks like a part of "Country", can I render country as a Separate item and make it disabled?
for example

Update 2: I have managed to disable items based on a logic, ItemDisabledFunc="@isDisabled" and then
private bool isDisabled(City city)

{
return true or false based on your logic
}

What do you mean by rendering customer html, do you want to add some html elements in Blazor Autocomplete, and not simply adjust the css style? BTW, judging from your tag, are you using Mudblazor Autocomplete?

Yes, it is mudblazor and I have updated the question with what I have done previously in bootstrap.


If user search for City2, I need to show Country1 as a heading and
then City1 under that heading and If user search for City1, I need to
show Country1 and then City and then Country2 and City

Based on your description and if I am understanding correctly that you mean "Country1-city2" and then "Country1-city1/Country2-city1" ,MudBlazor has provided the customizing html design.
1. Follow the document to enable MudBlazor in your project.
https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#prerequisites
2. Using ItemTemplate to render customized html elements
@page "/"

<MudGrid>

    <MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4">
        <MudAutocomplete T="City" Label="Search City" @bind-Value="selectedCity"
                         SearchFunc="@SearchCities" ToStringFunc="@(c => c == null ? null : $"{c.Country} - {c.Name}")">
            <ItemTemplate Context="city">
                <MudText>
                    @if (previousCountry == null || previousCountry != city.Country)
                    {
                        <div class="country-heading">@city.Country</div>
                    }
                    <div class="city-name">@city.Name</div>
                </MudText>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </MudAutocomplete>
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>

@code {
    private City selectedCity;
    private string previousCountry = null;

    private List<City> Cities = new List<City>
    {
        new City { Name = "City1", Country = "Country1" },
        new City { Name = "City2", Country = "Country1" },
        new City { Name = "City3", Country = "Country1" },
        new City { Name = "City1", Country = "Country2" },
        new City { Name = "City4", Country = "Country2" },
        new City { Name = "City5", Country = "Country2" },
        new City { Name = "City6", Country = "Country2" },
    };

    private Task<IEnumerable<City>> SearchCities(string value, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<City>>(Cities);

        var result = Cities.Where(city => city.Name.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                           .OrderBy(city => city.Country)
                           .ThenBy(city => city.Name);
        return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<City>>(result);
    }

    public class City
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}

Here is the doc https://mudblazor.com/components/autocomplete#presentation .
3. Test


